How to use ifelse inside aes in ggplot2?
I made a function to generate graphs in R and there's an argument called m_col, which is used when my graph has more than one column.
I tried this code:
generateGraph <- function(data, m_col = FALSE) {
  
  if(m_col == TRUE) {
    col <- names(data)[2]
  } else {
    col <- names(data)[1]
  }
  
  data |>
    select(everything(), var = {{col}}) |>
    ggplot(aes(x = ifelse(m_col == TRUE, reorder(var, -n), var),
               y = n,
               ymin = n_low,
               ymax = n_upp)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity",
             fill = "#273499",
             alpha = .8,
             width = .7)
  
}

generateGraph(question, m_col = TRUE)

The result is this:

But is supposed to be this:

What am I doing wrong?
My dput:
structure(list(resposta = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), levels = c("Não", "Sim"), class = "factor"), questao = c("Baixo número de candidatos(as) com a experiência necessária", 
"Não há interesse nesse tipo de trabalho", "Falta de qualificação para as vagas", 
"Muita competição de outras empresas pelos candidatos", "Distância e problemas de transporte", 
"Salários baixos", "Outros"), n = c(0.249678269126242, 0.0882252727404921, 
0.214696071646437, 0.0358608969946233, 0.0670295733380799, 0.0324488467977079, 
0.0262572373795945), n_low = c(0.201005459494235, 0.0573694113878506, 
0.168048082746628, 0.0143586248395167, 0.0409590734276312, 0.0142092731208629, 
0.00961143386157624), n_upp = c(0.298351078758249, 0.119081134093134, 
0.261344060546245, 0.0573631691497299, 0.0931000732485286, 0.0506884204745529, 
0.0429030408976127)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


Use if rather than ifelse
For example
ggplot(aes(x = if(m_col == TRUE) reorder(var, -n) else var,
           y = n,
           ymin = n_low,
           ymax = n_upp)) +

ifelse returns a vector equal to the length of the condition. So ifelse(TRUE, 1:5, 10) only returns 1 because length(TRUE)==1. You should not use ifelse for control flow, it's really only for transforming vectors.

Thank you! I did not know that you can use if inside ggplot.

Why use ``m_col == TRUE m_colis already TRUE or FALSE. so you mean to sayif(m_col)`
